# Characteristic polynomial question with Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Q: Suppose that $A$ is a $5x5$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $x^3(x-8)(x-3)$

a) Explain why Rank$(A)$ must be either $2, 3,$ or $ 4$?

b) Suppose that Rank$(A)$ = $3$, is $A$ diagonalizable?

Plz help.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Can $A$ be invertible? What does this say about its rank?

There are non-zero $x$ and $y$ such that $Ax=3x$ and $Ay=8y$, what does this say about the rank of $A$?

What does the characteristic polynomial of a diagonal matrix look like? When would it be $x^3(x-8)(x-3)$?